# How to freeze desktop icons 16.04 LTS Unity

Tags: 16.04, unity, permissions, icons, freeze

I am currently using a PC with ubuntu 16.04 LTS / 64 bits / Unity.

- Apart from some applications that I can run from the launcher I have put some "personal" scripts with their dedicated icons on the desktop.
  I appreciate having these icons at particular places on the screen.
- However it is clear that a left click /drag & drop can misplace my icons by mistake.
- How can I do to make sure that my icons/scripts cannot be moved around the screen by accident ? In other words is it possible to freeze the display ?

I thought changing the owner & group of the Desktop directory to root (with a sudo chown -R root:root Desktop) would do the trick but in fact it doesn't.

Any idea ?